# Eigenvalue multiplicity in matrices that differ by small amounts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let M $\in \mathbf{R^{n\times n}}$. Suppose all of the eigenvalues are distinct, then can we say that there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that every N $\in \mathbf{R^{n\times n}}$ has distinct eigenvalues if the coefficients of M and N differ by at most $\epsilon$?

Comment: yes, the eigenvalues are continuous in the entries

Comment: @Ollie Please add context and show your attempt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this follows from the continuity of the map, that associates to each matrix, its characteristic polynomial and the continuity of the simple" roots of real polynomials